# Display PopOver in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, nativescript

I've been working on getting the UIPrinterPicker to display on a iPad with NativeScript. I've received some great help from others.

The problem I have now is that the UIPrinterPicker PopOver doesn't display correctly on the iPad. As you can see in the image, the white bar underneath the time is the PopOver. I don't have any CSS applied and haven't found any documentation on styling a PopOver in NativeScript.

**Note:** I am able to get the UIPrinterPicker to display on the iPhone, as it doesn't require opening within an PopOver.

[image]

Below is the relevant code for the page:

```
var frames = require("ui/frame");
var view;

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    view = page.ios;
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;

function selectPrinter() {
    var runningOniPad = (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    var printPicker = UIPrinterPickerController.printerPickerControllerWithInitiallySelectedPrinter(null);
    var completionHandler = function(printerPicker, userDidSelect, error) {
                                if (error != null) {
                                    console.log("error: " + error);
                                }
                                global.selectedPrinter = printerPicker.selectedPrinter;
                                console.log("selectedPrinter: " + global.selectedPrinter);
                            };
    if ( ! runningOniPad) {
        printPicker.presentAnimatedCompletionHandler(false, completionHandler);
    } else {
        printPicker.presentFromRectInViewAnimatedCompletionHandler(view.view.frame, view.view, false, completionHandler);
    }

}
exports.selectPrinter = selectPrinter;
```

And below is the UI XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" >
        <StackLayout id="myStackLayout">
            <Button text="Select Printer" tap="selectPrinter" />
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Is there a way to display the PopOver correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your case and what I have done to show the PopOver under iPad is creating a custom view with initWithFrame like this:

```
else {

    var makeView = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame({origin: {x:0, y:0}, size: {width: 400, height: 600 } });

    printPicker.presentFromRectInViewAnimatedCompletionHandler(makeView.frame, view.view, false, completionHandler);
}
```

You can further customize your new view the native way.
Just in case you are wondering how to make relative the position of your custom view you can use something like this

```
var makeView = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame({
    origin: { x: view.view.frame.origin.x, 
              y: view.view.frame.origin.y }, 
    size: { width: view.view.bounds.size.width/2, 
            height: view.view.bounds.size.height/2 } 
});
```

I strongly recommend using a different words for your variable **view** to avoid confusion when reading something like **view.view**

Comment: Thanks Nick! I appreciate the help and agree that the variable naming could use some clean up.

Comment: Yep - I have myself fell in that trap during the test and wondered around with this view and view.view naming :)